# how do I delete library clearly in react native?

Tags: react-native

I want to delete react-native-google-signin library.

so I remove it using 'yarn remove react-native-google-signin'

But when I bulid my app, it seems to be there.[image]

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your scenario, after removing library or package you need to do pod install after that for iOS..

**SOLUTION**

if you are using yarn

```
yarn remove react-native-google-signin
```

If you are using npm

```
npm uninstall --save react-native-google-signin
```

After that move into your ios folder using `cd ios`

Then run pod install using `pod install`

Finally, close existing workspace from XCODE and reopen and before run your project clean your project ( Command+Shift+K ) and run

Comment: Did you try to close project and reopen and clean your project?

Comment: If you still facing issue try to manually remove  inside your Products folder from XCODE

Comment: Yes I did. I also even deleted contents in DerivedData folder and I tried to find any file including RNGoogleSignin with search in xcode. But there's no more content with RNGoogleSignin

Comment: I found it in General!! Thanks!

Comment: @GWANHUIKIM Gald it helps :)